# Can't load a 2.3 TB file into sparkling-water cluster with 10 TB memory

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, h2o, sparkling-water

Having the following issue with Sparkling-water version 2.2.9.  My Hadoop cluster is running CDH 5.13.  As per the H2o documentation, I should have roughly 4x the memory as the data size in the H2o/Sparkling-water cluster.

I can import a 750 GB data file (CSV) of size onto a sparkling-water cluster with 4 TB of memory (40 executors, 100GB each).  However having problems loading a larger data file.  This (CSV) file is roughly 2.2 TB in size (also have it in Parquet/Snappy format, 550GB in size).  I have created a Sparkling-water cluster with 100 executors of 100GB/executor.  The "parsing" step runs for about 60-70% and then the containers start failing with Error Code 143 and 255.  I have bumped up the memory to about 12 TB, still no success.

The python code is:

```
import h2o
h2o.init(ip='hdchdp01v03', port=9500, strict_version_check=False)
ls_hdfs="hdfs://HDCHDP01ns/h2o_test/csv_20171004"
print("Reading files from ", ls_hdfs)
sum_df = h2o.import_file(path = ls_hdfs, destination_frame="sum_df")
```

Has anyone run into similar issues? My Hadoop cluster only has 20 TB of memory, so hogging 12 TB memory itself would be a stretch most of the time.

With my first file, I see once the data is imported into the cluster, it seemed to take roughly double the file size in memory, but not sure how to recover the 4x memory I have allocated until the sparkling-water cluster comes down.

So, are there any other workarounds I could do to load this data into H2o for analysis with some due diligence on the available cluster memory?

Shankar

Comment: Curious if you were able to solve the problem? I am also having issues loading even smaller files into Sparkling Water.

Comment: I didn't have problem loading up to 100G worth of files into Sparkling Water DataFrame.  One thing I noticed was H2O prefers CSV format much better than Parquet.  For Parquet files, the memory requirement for the H2O cluster increases exponentially.

Comment: For loading large Parquet files, I finally settled on reading it into a Spark DF, then convert it into a H2O DF with this.  The more memory I gave, lesser it took to load.

Comment: import h2oContext.implicits._
val ls_file1="hdfs://<hdfs dir>"
val spark_DF = spark.read.parquet(ls_file1)
val hf: H2OFrame = spark_DF